# Oracle : Inserting large dataset into a table

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I need to load data from different remote database into our own database. I write a single "complex" query using WITH statement. It is around 18 Million rows of data.

What is most efficient way to do the insert?

1. using cursor insert one by one
2. using INSERT INTO

or is there any other way?

Comment: Some questions. Is this a one-off exercise or a regular occurence?  What is the time window for running the load?  How much latency can you have been the source and target databases?  How reliable is the connection between the databases?  Is the data in the source database static (archived) or dynamic (operational system)?  What you want to happen to the target database if the process fails halfway through (say you lose network connectivity)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastest way to do anything should be to use a single SQL statement.  The next most efficient approach is to use a cursor doing `BULK COLLECT` operations to minimize context shifts between the SQL and PL/SQL engines.  The least efficient approach is to use a cursor and process the data row-by-row.

Comment: Thank you, BULK COLLECT is really helpful. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

As Justin wrote, the most efficient approach is to use a single SQL statement ( insert into ... select ... ). Additionally you can take advantage of [direct-path insert](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/tables.htm#ADMIN01509)

Answer (score 0):

18 million rows will require quite a bit of rollback for your single insert stmt scenario.  A cursor for loop would be much slower but you'd be able to commit every x rows.

Personally, I'd go old school and dump out to a file and load via sqlldr or data pump, esp as this is across databases.

Comment: Bear in mind that committing every *x* rows leads to more work when restarting the load process after an ABEND.  Also there are scenarios when it may not make sense to expose a partial load to the wider gaze.  However I do agree that 18 million rows is a lot to push through a single transaction.

Comment: Also 18 million inserts won't generate as much rollback as you might think: it's basically 18 million rowids and some metadata.  It's just a question of getting the DBA to size the UNDO tablespace appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Data Synchronisation Studio](http://www.simego.com/Products/Data-Synchronisation-Studio) and change the select statement to take 1 million at a time (I think 18m at once would probably overload your machine)